Track object status by only logging tainted fields
When I am developing complex logic across multiple classes, I often log entities (often with toString() underneath) to check the status of the object, which field has what value. I always find logs unnecessarily verbose, printing all fields. It is hard to track:

what has been changed and
when it is changed

when an entity goes a long way through a bunch of classes.
I would like to see only "tainted" fields (the fields which are already changed/set before reaching the logging line of code). I imagine a solution like this:

set a value to a field
add this field to a map, for example taintedFields; key is field name and value is actual value. Ideally, do this in every setter. Better yet, an abstract class with such setter template as base class for all model classes/DTOs, so that every setter would do super.tainted(field, value) before setting the value
when printing, only print this map; other null/empty values are ignored

The idea is not hard to implement, but I wonder is this practical? Is it good practice? Is there any existing solution? I cannot be the first person ever to think about this. Any better way to do it?
Last edit:
I understand the reason why this question is closed and I am OK with that, it has no fact based answer but here is the only place I can think of to collect opinions about it.
At last I think this is valid idea but several difficulties may be encountered:

add a base class for all model/DTOs classes is much work in a big project; maybe create a super class and inherit when needed; or an annotation?
reflection is inevitable, as we want to make every existing and newly added fields in the future to be able to mark status of tainted or not; so a map with keys of fields name is needed
maybe furthermore, not only tainted or not, but also when and where(in which class, which method and on which line) it is changed is also desirable to include in some log lines; but this is beyond simple code change; interceptors may be needed(but aroundInvoke only works when entering and exiting method, still cannot detect what happens in between lines)


The idea of tracking changed fields can be practical especially in complex logic, and you are right your idea is easy to implement but it is important to test it for performance issues since you are going to add another layer of complexity to your codebase and would add more hard work to the maintenance of your application.
I usually depend on debugging remotely and locally most of the time and i rarely use logs for testing.
I know in the other hand that debugging work best on objects and logic layer and its difficult to use it in other layer such as persistence or with middleware when working on big complex projects.
So what I propose is you can use your method on certain critical logic to get real time results but I recommend using unit testing with  Mockito it is really helpful to mock your services and injecting directly your values without doing the business logic again and you can use DiffBuilder class to track differences between objects.

OK remote debugging, that I have not thought of. I need to check how to do that in a kubernete/openshift environment. DiffBuilder I haven't heard of, but I will check it too.

You can make it a little simpler - a boolean array held in every class you want to audit. each cell in the array will correspond to a field (you can arbitrary choose the order). When you call a setter for a field, the setter will also flip the array's corresponding cell from false to true. When you call toString to print the instance's fields, the method will only print out the fields which have their corresponding cell in the array as true - and once it's done printing, toString will reset all the cells in the array back to false. This way you'll only print out fields which have been set to a new value since you last did an audit print, and you won't have to handle a map object which will be resource wasteful.

Thanks. I like to save space but I am afraid my little brain may forget about to expand the array when I add more fields and when that happens, a simple log line will cause a ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException...

@WesternGun not to worry - you can have the toString and setter methods be patient with you - if the array doesn't cover all the fields (let's say you've added a few new fields and did not expend it) you can just default to the original behavior - set the value, print the value, just like before. This way you won't trigger the index out of bounds.
